# Как сохранять информацию юзера. Aiogram

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram, config, save

У меня возник вопрос, а как сохранять информацию юзера.
Вот к примеру самое элементарное. Юзер нажимает по кнопке и ему даются баллы. Он нажал к примеру 10 раз, а после хочет узнать, сколько раз он нажал, написав команду /stats. Каким образом я могу сохранить это значение?

Comment: сохраняйте в базу данных

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько вариантов:

- База данных (sqlite, mysql, postgresql)
- Переменные (информация удаляется при перезапуске, полезно, чтобы не создавать большую нагрузку)
- Сохранение в файлы (json, xml)

Я использую первые два, в зависимости от задачи.
В вашем случае наиболее правильно будет использовать бд.
Код sqlite3:

```
import sqlite3
class database:
    def __init__(self, db_file):
        self.connection=sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        self.cursor=connection.cursor()
        self.cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
            `user_id` VARCHAR(999) NULL,
            `count` INTEGER DEFAULT '0'
        );""")
        self.connection.commit()

    def add_user(self, user_id: int) -> None:
        self.cursor.execute(
            'INSERT INTO `users` (?,?)', (user_id, 0))
        self.connection.commit()

    def user_exists(self, user_id: int) -> bool:
        result = self.cursor.execute(
            "SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = ?", (user_id,))
        return bool(len(result.fetchall()))

    def count(self, user_id: int) -> None:
        self.cursor.execute(
            'UPDATE `users` SET `count` = `count`+1 WHERE `user_id` = ?', (user_id,))
        self.connection.commit()

    def get_user(self, user_id: int) -> int:
        result=self.cursor.execute(
            'SELECT `count` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = ?', (user_id,))
        return result.fetchone()[0]
```

Как использовать:

```
#Создаем объект базы данных
database=database('db.db')

#Скажем, это хендлер
#Сначала проверяем есть ли такой пользак
if not database.user_exists(call.message.chat.id):
    #если пользака нет - создаем его
    database.add_user(call.message.chat.id)

#добавляем стату
database.count(call.message.chat.id)


#Взять же статистику из бд можно так:
count=database.get_user(call.message.chat.id)
#count здесь - кол-во нажатий (действий)
```